# Finding a Perfect substring in a string in ruby

Tags: ruby

A String s comprised of numbers from 0-9 contains a perfect substring if all the elements within a substring occurs exactly k times. Calculate the number of perfect substrings in s.

**EXAMPLE**

s = '1102021222'
k = 2

Here s contains 6 substrings:

1. 11
2. 0202
3. 110202
4. 102021
5. 22
6. 22

Can anyone help me with the solution to this in Ruby with the least complexity?
TIA..

Comment: What do you have so far? Show your attempt(s) please.

Comment: if you clarify your question with an edit it might be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
def count_em(str, k)
  enum = str.each_char
  (k..str.size).step(k).sum do |n|
     enum.each_cons(n).count do |a|
       a.tally.all? { |_k,v| v == k }
     end
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
str = '1102021222'
```

```
count_em(str, 1) #=> 18 ( 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
                 #       10, 02, 20, 02, 21, 12, 102, 021
count_em(str, 2) #=>  6 (11, 22, 22, 0202, 110202, 102021)
count_em(str, 3) #=>  1 (102021)
count_em(str, n) #=>  0 for n > 3
```

**Explanation**

[Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) made its debut in Ruby v2.7. To support earlier versions of Ruby replace `tally` with

```
each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }
```

[Enumerable#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) was new in Ruby 2.4. To support earlier versions of Ruby replace `sum` with

```
reduce(:+)
```

See also [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons), [Enumerable#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) and [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) and [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).

Note that no strings having `k` instances of all unique digits contained in the string could be produced for values of `n` that are not multiples of `k`. It is for that reason that `step(k)` is present.

The easiest way to explain the calculations is to salt the method with `puts` statements and run it.

```
def count_em(str, k)
  puts "k = #{k}"
  enum0 = str.each_char
  puts "enum0 = #{enum0}"
  (k..str.size).step(k).sum do |n|
    puts "n = #{n}"
    enum1 = enum0.each_cons(n)
    puts "  enum1.to_a = #{enum1.to_a}"
    enum1.count do |a|
      puts "  a = #{a}"
      h = a.tally
      puts "    a.tally = #{h}"
      puts "    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = #{h.all? {|_k,v| v==k}}"
      h.all? { |_k,v| v==k }
    end
  end
end
```

The line `puts "  enum1.to_a = #{enum1.to_a}"` merely displays the values that will be generated by the enumerator `enum1` and passed to `count`'s block.

Try it for `k = 2`:

```
count_em(str, 2)
  #=> 6
```

displays the following:

```
k = 2
enum0 = #<Enumerator:0x00007f9467ab60f0>
```

```
n = 2
  enum1.to_a = [["1", "1"], ["1", "0"], ["0", "2"], ["2", "0"],
                ["0", "2"], ["2", "1"], ["1", "2"], ["2", "2"],
                ["2", "2"]]
  a = ["1", "1"]
    a.tally = {"1"=>2}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = true
  a = ["1", "0"]
    a.tally = {"1"=>1, "0"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["0", "2"]
    a.tally = {"0"=>1, "2"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["2", "0"]
    a.tally = {"2"=>1, "0"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["0", "2"]
    a.tally = {"0"=>1, "2"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["2", "1"]
    a.tally = {"2"=>1, "1"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["1", "2"]
    a.tally = {"1"=>1, "2"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["2", "2"]
    a.tally = {"2"=>2}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = true
  a = ["2", "2"]
    a.tally = {"2"=>2}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = true
```

```
n = 4
  enum1.to_a = [["1", "1", "0", "2"], ["1", "0", "2", "0"],
                ["0", "2", "0", "2"], ["2", "0", "2", "1"],
                ["0", "2", "1", "2"], ["2", "1", "2", "2"],
                ["1", "2", "2", "2"]]
  a = ["1", "1", "0", "2"]
    a.tally = {"1"=>2, "0"=>1, "2"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["1", "0", "2", "0"]
    a.tally = {"1"=>1, "0"=>2, "2"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["0", "2", "0", "2"]
    a.tally = {"0"=>2, "2"=>2}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = true
  a = ["2", "0", "2", "1"]
    a.tally = {"2"=>2, "0"=>1, "1"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["0", "2", "1", "2"]
    a.tally = {"0"=>1, "2"=>2, "1"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["2", "1", "2", "2"]
    a.tally = {"2"=>3, "1"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["1", "2", "2", "2"]
    a.tally = {"1"=>1, "2"=>3}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
```

```
n = 6
  enum1.to_a = [["1", "1", "0", "2", "0", "2"], ["1", "0", "2", "0", "2", "1"],
                ["0", "2", "0", "2", "1", "2"], ["2", "0", "2", "1", "2", "2"],
                ["0", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2"]]
  a = ["1", "1", "0", "2", "0", "2"]
    a.tally = {"1"=>2, "0"=>2, "2"=>2}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = true
  a = ["1", "0", "2", "0", "2", "1"]
    a.tally = {"1"=>2, "0"=>2, "2"=>2}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = true
  a = ["0", "2", "0", "2", "1", "2"]
    a.tally = {"0"=>2, "2"=>3, "1"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["2", "0", "2", "1", "2", "2"]
    a.tally = {"2"=>4, "0"=>1, "1"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["0", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2"]
    a.tally = {"0"=>1, "2"=>4, "1"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
```

```
n = 8 
  enum1.to_a = [["1", "1", "0", "2", "0", "2", "1", "2"],
                ["1", "0", "2", "0", "2", "1", "2", "2"],
                ["0", "2", "0", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2"]]
  a = ["1", "1", "0", "2", "0", "2", "1", "2"]
    a.tally = {"1"=>3, "0"=>2, "2"=>3}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["1", "0", "2", "0", "2", "1", "2", "2"]
    a.tally = {"1"=>2, "0"=>2, "2"=>4}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
  a = ["0", "2", "0", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2"]
    a.tally = {"0"=>2, "2"=>5, "1"=>1}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
```

```
n = 10
  enum1.to_a = [["1", "1", "0", "2", "0", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2"]]
  a = ["1", "1", "0", "2", "0", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2"]
    a.tally = {"1"=>3, "0"=>2, "2"=>5}
    a.tally.all? {|_k,v| v == k} = false
```

Comment: @Stefan, I edited to incorporate two of your three suggestions (adding `step(k)` and replacing what I had previously with `a.tally.all? { |_k,v| v == k }`). I made a few other changes as well. I like your third suggestion as well but agree it can be left as an "excercise for the reader". Thank you for your thoughts.